# Python Keras Sequential model input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I have an array for attempting some [times series sliding window method for machine learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-multilayer-perceptron-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) forecasting with tf.Keras:

`X.shape`

`(8779, 6, 1)`

to fit the MLP model:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Could anyone give me a tip on how to correct this model input?

```
input_shape=(6,)
```

I cant figure out to how get past this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape (None, 6, 1)
```

Comment: I think you need to set `input_shape=6` instead of `input=(6,)`

Comment: change to `input_shape=(6,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Even though it was solved by a recommendation from comments, here is the solution:

Changing:

```
input_shape=(6,)
```

Into:

```
input_shape=(6,1)
```

worked.